# JDBC Multiple Columns with the same name

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, jdbc, javafx

I'm having a problem with the value being populated from a column from a different table instead of the table I'm wanting it to pull from.

From mySQL, I get the desired result of null; however, from within the program, it is displaying the value (If I have given it one for that row,) or the value from a different table. This is even while using aliases and explicitly stating which table to pull from.

I have a device table and a device type table. The device table has all the same fields as the device, but it is just 1's and 0's that dictate which fields are needed. (This is used when generating the edit / create a device GUI form.)

This only happens when using the `resultSet.getInt("column_with_issue")` if the values are `INT`s in both tables. It is returning a proper null when I do a `resultSet.getString("column_with_no_issues")` as long as the types are different.

Here is my original query, and what I've tried to change as per suggestion to fix it.

```
SELECT d.*, dt.type, os.os_name FROM device d inner join device_type dt on d.type_id = dt.id left outer join operating_system os on d.os = os.id 
WHERE d.division_number = 1 or 1
AND (d.asset_tag = 1 or 1)
AND (dt.type = 1 or 1);
```

Possible fix as described in other peoples stackoverflow/javaranch questions. This will give each specific column its own name. However even when I go to pull from (as an example one that has two different variable types) `dwireless`, I still get the integer value that should be from my `device_type.wireless` for that kind of device instead of the expected null value.

```
SELECT d.id as did, d.division_number as ddivision_number, d.current_location as dcurrent_location, d.type_id as dtype_id, d.model as dmodel, d.asset_tag as dasset_tag, d.serial_number as dserial_number, d.manufacture_date as dmanufacture_date, d.screen as dscreen, d.os as dos, d.users_name as dusers_name, d.office_installed as doffice_installed, d.memory as dmemory, d.series as dseries, d.ip_address as dip_address, d.host_name as dhostname, d.vm_host as dvm_host, d.processor as dprocessor, d.wireless as dwireless, d.purchase_quality as dpurchase_quality, d.purchase_price as dpurchase_price, d.active as dactive, d.notes as dnotes, dt.type, os.os_name 
FROM device d inner join device_type dt on d.type_id = dt.id left outer join operating_system os on d.os = os.id 
WHERE d.division_number = 1 or 1
AND (d.asset_tag = 1 or 1)
AND (dt.type = 1 or 1);
```

Here is the Java code that I'm using to pull the variables from the result set.

```
private ObservableList<Device> getDevices(String sqlStatement) throws SQLException {
        ObservableList<Device> devices = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        // Run the query to select all of our devices.
        Statement searchDeviceStatement = Main.myConn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = searchDeviceStatement.executeQuery(sqlStatement);

        // Add all of our devices into our array list to be displayed.
        // These are the actual columns of the database.
        while (rs.next()) {
            devices.add(new Device(rs.getInt("did"), rs.getInt("ddivision_number"), rs.getInt("dtype_id"),
                    rs.getString("type"), rs.getString("dmodel"), rs.getInt("dasset_tag"), rs.getString("dserial_number"),
                    rs.getInt("dmanufacture_date"), rs.getString("dscreen"), rs.getInt("dos"), rs.getString("os_name"),
                    rs.getString("dusers_name"), rs.getInt("doffice_installed"), rs.getString("dmemory"),
                    rs.getString("dseries"), rs.getString("dip_address"), rs.getString("dhost_name"),
                    rs.getString("dvm_host"), rs.getString("dprocessor"), rs.getInt("dwireless"),
                    rs.getString("dpurchase_quality"), rs.getDouble("dpurchase_price"), rs.getInt("dactive"), rs.getString("dnotes")));
        }
        return devices;
    }
```

The query works as intended from mySQL Workbench, as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avGRw.png), but when displaying the data in my program it looks like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iI32t.png)

Answer (score 0):

Answer: I am an idiot. Default values for integers are 0, while strings are null. JDBC is returning null but when it creates my Device object with that value it is defaulted to 0. This is explained about 1/3rd of the way down on [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) page.